# Azure:How to create a VM from MarketPlace using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

How can I create a VM from New MarketPlace through PowerShell scripts? I want to create "SQL Server 2014 Enterprise on Windows Server 2012 R2" VM which is available on Preview Azure Portal.

Get-AzureVMImage cmdlet does not return "SQL Server 2014 Enterprise on Windows Server 2012 R2" VM.

the following command returns no result

```
Get-AzureVMImage | where {$_.Label -like "SQL Server 2014 Enterprise on Windows Server 2012 R2*"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -
Get-AzureVMImage | where {$_.Label -like "SQL Server 2014 RTM Enterprise on Windows Server 2012 R2*"}